Theorems related to Chevalley's theorem
Recently I have read Chevalley's theorem of a complete local ring which basically says that if $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a complete local ring and if $\{b_n\}$ be a sequence of ideals such that $b_n \supseteq b_{n+1}$ and $\bigcap b_n=0$ then $\{b_n\}$ is finer than the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology. I was wondering if anyone knows any theorem similar to this, that is a Hausdorff topology is finer than the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology, without assuming that $R$ is complete.
